Strange behavior and rendering on model.set() command
At the beginning, I've added a property to the model:
this.model = new Model()
this.model.set("level","test")

In another routine, I've to refresh this "level" property because in a .dust file I've this:
<h3><div class="col-md-9 textebleu">Level value: {level}</div></h3>

The routine is:
// I HAVE the values!
alert(this.model.get('level') // Return the initial 'test' value
this.model.set('level',"other") // CLEANS all others elements but {level} is well refreshed

the ".set()" seems to trigger a refresh but all others elements ... and{level} is well refreshed
Does anybody have an idea?
I've tried to set an other property like this.model.set("tt,'ssss') and it makes the same problem. Tried to change this.model.attributes.leve= "ddd" the valu evolving but "level" is not refreshed on screen.
